# Security Token for EOS

Tags: eosio.token

What functions need to be added to the standard EOSIO.token to use it as a base for a security token?

I could find some interesting documentation for ethereum (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1462) that could be easily translated in an extension of EOSIO.token, but I was wondering if the discussion already started somewhere for Eos?